# Class issue python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn more about objects, and from what I understood, self doesn't take any value. Why does this method asks for another argument when I try to call it?
Thanks.

```
class School:
        def __init__(self):
            self.roster =  []
            self.dicti = {1:[],
                         2:[],
                         3:[],
                         4:[],
                         5:[]}
                         
        def add_student(self,name,grade):
            if name in self.dicti[grade]:
                raise ValueError("The student is already added to the grade")
            else:
                self.dicti[grade].append(name)
            
    
    
            
    x = School
    print(x.add_student("radu",2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the class. In your penultimate line:

```
x = School()
```

Without the paranthesis, `x` is just a reference to `School`. You need to "call" `School()` to construct and initialise an object and assign it to `x`.

What is happening under the hood is that when you have an object of the class, `self` is automatically replaced with a reference to the object. Without instantiating the class, this cannot be done, therefore python asks you to provide another argument to take the position of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the class as Sarema wrote. You also don't return anything from the add_student function, so the print will write `None`

```
class School:
    def __init__(self):
        self.roster = []
        self.dicti = {1: [],
                      2: [],
                      3: [],
                      4: [],
                      5: []}

    def add_student(self, name, grade):
        if name in self.dicti[grade]:
            raise ValueError("The student is already added to the grade")
        else:
            self.dicti[grade].append(name)
            return f"Added {name} to list grade: {grade}. " \
                   f"\nGrade {grade} list: {self.dicti[grade]}"


x = School()
print(x.add_student("radu", 2))
```

returns

```
Added radu to list grade: 2. 
Grade 2 list: ['radu']
```